# How to add Custom UI when we try to perform single sign on using Azure Active Directory Account login?

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services, azure-connect

Am developing a Windows Store 8.1 app using C# and xaml.

I am doing Single sign on using Azure Active Directory Account login.

I do not want users to be redirected to the Microsoft Account login screen, and then come back. I want to supply them with the login credential screen where we capture their username and password, and then we want to programatically do the authentication against Azure AD, and get back the claims identity.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported scenario for security concerns. One of the value propositions for AAD is that the password management, across the whole login lifecycle, is managed and secure. This is particularly important for scenarios in which AAD is securing a 3rd-party SaaS solution. A developer should not be able to have access to a user's credentials at any point.

All that said, it sounds like there is another question here which is answerable: How can I customize the login screen that AAD gives me?

AAD Premium does offer features for [adding custom branding to your tenant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532270.aspx). However, you still will be working with a screen that is provided for you.